# confused about the way exponential PDF is used

Tags: exponential-function

I'm studying a paper called "[Optimization based on bacterial chemotaxis](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/985689)". As it can be understood from its name, it has proposed an optimization algorithm based on the reaction of a bacterium toward its environment. The bacterium tends to go towards chemoattractants and stay away from repellents. The path of the bacterium consists of a sequence of straight-line trajectories that each of them has a different direction and duration.

In order to compute the duration of each trajectory, it has been written in the paper that:

> Compute the duration of the trajectory $τ$ from the distribution of a
>   random variable with an exponential probability density function:
>
> $$P(X=τ) = 1/T e^{-τ/T}$$
>
> where for $f_pr / l_pr >= 0$, $T=T_0$ and for $f_pr / l_pr < 0$,
>   $T=T_0 (1+b\mid f_pr / l_pr|)$

I'm new to this field, but according to what I've studied [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/pdf-is-not-a-probability-5a4b8a5d9531?gi=ecb09a12896b), my question is that since the duration is computed by exponential PDF, shouldn't they use $f(τ)$ instead of $P(X=τ)$? If not, what does $P(X=τ)$ mean here?

Comment: It's an abuse of notation some people use for continuous densities.  Formally speaking, yes, it's an error.

Comment: @BrianMoehring In another part of this paper, this value is called probability density distribution. Is PDF different from probability density distribution?

Comment: its the same thing